# How to avoid hidden files in file picker using tkinter filedialog.askopenfilename method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to allow the users to select CSV files from the file manager. But it shows all hidden folders too, which is very inappropriate. How can I avoid hidden folders?

```
def importCSV(self):
            self.file =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("CSV files","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
```

Answer (score 9):

After a bit of searching around I managed to find the answer [here](https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-tkinter-discuss/3723/). I did some slight changes to the linked example so it will run on Python 3. To test it out, simply press `ctrl+o` after executing.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

try:
    # call a dummy dialog with an impossible option to initialize the file
    # dialog without really getting a dialog window; this will throw a
    # TclError, so we need a try...except :
    try:
        root.tk.call('tk_getOpenFile', '-foobarbaz')
    except TclError:
        pass
    # now set the magic variables accordingly
    root.tk.call('set', '::tk::dialog::file::showHiddenBtn', '1')
    root.tk.call('set', '::tk::dialog::file::showHiddenVar', '0')
except:
    pass

# a simple callback for testing:
def openfile(event):
    fname = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/', title='Select file', filetypes=(('CSV files', '*.csv'), ('all files', '*.*')))
    print(fname)
root.bind('<Control-o>', openfile)

root.mainloop()
```

The `showHiddenVar` is used to select if the hidden files will be displayed by default or not. If you don't want to allow the users to toggle between displaying and hiding the hidden files, then simply set `showHiddenBtn` to `'0'`.

Comment: do you have a sense how this could be modified to work with https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?

Comment: I managed to make it work, this was very useful, I think the answer would be better if you explained the importance of the inner `try except` block, that threw me off initially

Comment: @Manolis Agkopian - It would be quite useful to explain why the try-catch block is needed. Thanks!

Comment: @VikasGoel That wasn't my code, it was adapted based on the code I found on the link to the discussion I posted above. Which unfortunately is dead now and archive.org doesn't have it. Either way, I think the purpose is explained in the comments inside the code.

Comment: @ManolisAgkopian - thanks for the reply (and for posting the solution). The code documents the intent, but not the reason why it is throwing error. Perhaps orthogonal to the original question, but still, good to know why a hack is needed.

Answer (score -1):

`filedialog.askopenfilename` This line just opens a file picker of the Operating System. This is *not* Python's file picker.

You can disable the option to `show hidden files` in your operating system and they will disappear in the file picker too.

For windows, This option is available in File Explorer options in the Control Panel.

For Ubuntu, This option is available at  `filemanager > top menu->View->Show hidden files`

Comment: I've already disabled 'show hidden files' option. But still the same issue.

Comment: I was able to not show and show the hidden files. By using the same option. Which operating system are you using.

Comment: Linux ubuntu 18.04

Comment: `filemanager > top menu->View->Show hidden files`, Uncheck this, And the hidden files will be gone. But If the the user has his own hidden files on they will still be visible.

Comment: I've done this and hidden files are not displaying in my file manager. But in file picker in python Tkinter app all hidden folders are showing. I'm expecting some tricks using regular expressions. I've tried some but doesn't work.

Comment: can you run `nano ~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini` ? check parameter ShowHidden=blablabla inside those configuration file?

Comment: above are Ubuntu configuration for file chooser dialog, not nautilus file manager, because what you exactly want is file chooser I guess

Comment: @adadion ShowHidden=false

Comment: @adadion
I'm concerned about the file picker in the GUI app using Tkinter.

Comment: @BlockchainExperts Make a custom file chooser using `os.walk()` and only list the files that you need.

Comment: @BlockchainExperts in addition with @Vineeth suggestion, instead create custom file chooser and only list files that you need, you can list all files and folder without `.` as its first name if your program will run on Unix environment, whether using os.walk() or os.listdir()