# Program Toplevel freezing during the execution of a function in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter app that is structured like that:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class TopLevelWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kargs):
        super().__init__(root, *args, **kargs)
        self.root = root
        self.button= ttk.Button(self, text="Exportar excel", command=self.go)
        self.button.pack()
        self.prog_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient = "horizontal", mode= "determinate")
        self.prog_bar.pack()

    def go(self):
        global dic_Data
        # Create word file
        value_bar = 100/len(dic_Data)
        for k, v in dic_Data.items():
            # Calculate some stuff
            # Create Pil images and add them to the word file
            # Create Matplotlib images and add them to the word file
            self.prog_bar["value"] += value_bar
            self.root.update_idletasks()
        #Save the word file
        self.quit()
        self.destroy()


class App():
    def __init__(self, root, *params):
        self.root = root
        # Code
        # dic_Data gets populated

    def open_window(self):
        popup = TopLevelWindow(self.root)
        popup.mainloop()


dic_Data = {}

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The problem I'm having is that the function `go` ends up freezing my Toplevel window.

What is weird is that is starts doing okey for the first items of the for loop,
then it freezes but the functions keeps running fine (no visual updates on the bar),
until the for loop finishes and after that the windows closes as its suposed to and everything unfreezes again.

Why is that happening and could it be fixed?

EDITED:
One answer suggests to use the root.after function to avoid freezing but im having problems implementing it. This is what i have:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class TopLevelWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kargs):
        super().__init__(root, *args, **kargs)
        self.root = root
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Exportar excel", command=self.go)
        self.button.pack()
        self.prog_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient = "horizontal", mode= "determinate")
        self.prog_bar.pack()

    def heavy_function(self, k, v):
        # Calculate some stuff
        # Create Pil images and add the to the word file
        # Create Matplotlib images and add the to the word file
        # Add changes to word file
        self.prog_bar["value"] += value_bar

    def save_word(self):
        #Save the word file
        self.quit()
        self.destroy()

    def go(self):
        global dic_Data
        # Create word file
        value_bar = 100/len(dic_Data)
        for k, v in dic_Data.items():
            self.root.after(10, lambda: self.heavy_function(k, v))
        self.root.after(10, self.save_word)


class App():
    def __init__(self, root, *params):
        self.root = root
        # Code
        # dic_Data gets populated

    def open_window(self):
        popup = TopLevelWindow(self.root)
        popup.mainloop()


dic_Data = {}

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I gess for me beacause my operations inside the loop are more computing intensive it freezes, but I dont know why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to implement Roland Smith answer option 1.
Now it works, hopefuly this makes sense:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class TopLevelWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kargs):
        super().__init__(root, *args, **kargs)
        self.root = root
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Exportar excel", command=self.go)
        self.button.pack()
        self.prog_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient = "horizontal", mode= "determinate")
        self.prog_bar.pack()

    def heavy_function(self):
        try:
            k, v = next(self.order)
        except StopIteration:
            self.after(10, self.save_word)
            return
        # Calculate some stuff
        # Create Pil images and add the to the word file
        # Create Matplotlib images and add the to the word file
        self.prog_bar["value"] += self.value_bar
        self.after(10, self.heavy_function)

    def save_word(self):
        #Save the word file
        self.quit()
        self.destroy()

    def go(self):
        global dic_Data
        # Create word file
        self.value_bar = 100/len(dic_Data)
        self.order = iter(dic_Data.items())
        self.after(10, self.heavy_function)


class App():
    def __init__(self, root, *params):
        self.root = root
        # Code
        # dic_Data gets populated

    def open_window(self):
        popup = TopLevelWindow(self.root)
        popup.mainloop()


dic_Data = {}

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** What happens is that `self.go` simply takes too long and stops the processing of events.

Callbacks like `self.go` are executed **in** the `mainloop` whenever you activate a control.
*As long as the callback is is running, event processing is interrupted.*
So if said callback takes more than say 50 ms, you will notice it.

There are basically three ways to do long-running jobs in programs that use event-driven toolkits like tkinter.

1. Chop up the long running jobs in small pieces that are executed using the `after` method. This makes it easy to update a progress bar. An example from my own code is shown below.
2. Execute the long-running job in a separate process with `multiprocessing`. This will definitely *not* block the GUI. But you will need to use communication primitives to tell the GUI that an action is finished, and the GUI has to check those regularly using the `after` method.
3. Execute the long-running job in a separate thread. An additional complication is that in CPython only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode. So this is not *guaranteed* to be free from blocking the GUI. But in general, Python 3 tries to switch threads pretty often.
   You will need a `tkinter` that is built with threading enabled.
   An example is shown below.

### Example of (1): unlocking excel files using small steps

```
"""Remove passwords from modern excel 2007+ files (xlsx, xlsm)."""

from types import SimpleNamespace
import os
import re
import shutil
import stat
import sys
import zipfile

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.font import nametofont
import tkinter as tk

__version__ = "2022.01.28"
widgets = SimpleNamespace()
state = SimpleNamespace()


def create_widgets(root, w):
    """Create the window and its widgets.
    Arguments:
        root: the root window.
        w: SimpleNamespace to store widgets.
    """
    # Set the font.
    default_font = nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
    default_font.configure(size=12)
    root.option_add("*Font", default_font)
    # General commands and bindings
    root.bind_all('q', do_exit)
    root.wm_title('Unlock excel files v' + __version__)
    root.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
    # First row
    ttk.Label(root, text='(1)').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
    w.fb = ttk.Button(root, text="Select file", command=do_file)
    w.fb.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="w")
    w.fn = ttk.Label(root)
    w.fn.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
    # Second row
    ttk.Label(root, text='(2)').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
    w.backup = tk.IntVar()
    w.backup.set(0)
    ttk.Checkbutton(root, text='backup', variable=w.backup,
                    command=on_backup).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')
    w.suffixlabel = ttk.Label(root, text='suffix:', state=tk.DISABLED)
    w.suffixlabel.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='ew')
    w.suffix = tk.StringVar()
    w.suffix.set('-orig')
    se = ttk.Entry(root, justify='left', textvariable=w.suffix, state=tk.DISABLED)
    se.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky='w')
    w.suffixentry = se
    # Third row
    ttk.Label(root, text='(3)').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew')
    w.gobtn = ttk.Button(root, text="Go!", command=do_start, state=tk.DISABLED)
    w.gobtn.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ew')
    # Fourth row
    ttk.Label(root, text='(4)').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='ew')
    ttk.Label(root, text='Progress:').grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')
    # Fifth row
    sb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical")
    w.status = tk.Listbox(root, width=60, yscrollcommand=sb.set)
    w.status.grid(row=4, rowspan=5, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew")
    sb.grid(row=4, rowspan=5, column=5, sticky="ns")
    sb.config(command=w.status.yview)
    # Ninth row
    ttk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=do_exit).grid(row=9, column=1, sticky='ew')


def initialize_state(s):
    """
    Initialize the global state.
    Arguments:
        s: SimpleNamespace to store application state.
    """
    s.interval = 10
    s.path = ''
    s.inzf, s.outzf = None, None
    s.infos = None
    s.currinfo = None
    s.worksheets_unlocked = 0
    s.workbook_unlocked = False
    s.directory = None
    s.remove = None


def statusmsg(text):
    """Append a message to the status listbox, and make sure it is visible."""
    widgets.status.insert(tk.END, text)
    widgets.status.see(tk.END)


# Step functions to call in the after() method.
def step_open_zipfiles():
    path = widgets.fn['text']
    state.path = path
    statusmsg(f'Opening “{path}”...')
    first, last = path.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)
    if widgets.backup.get():
        backupname = first + widgets.suffix.get() + '.' + last
    else:
        backupname = first + '-orig' + '.' + last
        state.remove = backupname
    shutil.move(path, backupname)
    state.inzf = zipfile.ZipFile(backupname, mode="r")
    state.outzf = zipfile.ZipFile(
        path, mode="w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=1
    )
    root.after(state.interval, step_discover_internal_files)


def step_discover_internal_files():
    statusmsg(f'Reading “{state.path}”...')
    state.infos = [name for name in state.inzf.infolist()]
    state.currinfo = 0
    statusmsg(f'“{state.path}” contains {len(state.infos)} internal files.')
    root.after(state.interval, step_filter_internal_file)


def step_filter_internal_file():
    current = state.infos[state.currinfo]
    stat = f'Processing “{current.filename}” ({state.currinfo+1}/{len(state.infos)})...'
    statusmsg(stat)
    # Doing the actual work
    regex = None
    data = state.inzf.read(current)
    if b'sheetProtect' in data:
        regex = r'<sheetProtect.*?/>'
        statusmsg(f'Worksheet "{current.filename}" is protected.')
    elif b'workbookProtect' in data:
        regex = r'<workbookProtect.*?/>'
        statusmsg('The workbook is protected')
    else:
        state.outzf.writestr(current, data)
    if regex:
        text = data.decode('utf-8')
        newtext = re.sub(regex, '', text)
        if len(newtext) != len(text):
            state.outzf.writestr(current, newtext)
            state.worksheets_unlocked += 1
            statusmsg(f'Removed password from "{current.filename}".')
    # Next iteration or next step.
    state.currinfo += 1
    if state.currinfo >= len(state.infos):
        statusmsg('All internal files processed.')
        state.currinfo = None
        root.after(state.interval, step_close_zipfiles)
    else:
        root.after(state.interval, step_filter_internal_file)


def step_close_zipfiles():
    statusmsg(f'Writing “{state.path}”...')
    state.inzf.close()
    state.outzf.close()
    state.inzf, state.outzf = None, None
    root.after(state.interval, step_finished)


def step_finished():
    if state.remove:
        os.chmod(state.remove, stat.S_IWRITE)
        os.remove(state.remove)
        state.remove = None
    else:
        statusmsg('Removing temporary file')
    statusmsg(f'Unlocked {state.worksheets_unlocked} worksheets.')
    statusmsg('Finished!')
    widgets.gobtn['state'] = 'disabled'
    widgets.fn['text'] = ''
    state.path = ''


# Widget callbacks
def do_file():
    """Callback to open a file"""
    if not state.directory:
        state.directory = ''
        available = [os.environ[k] for k in ('HOME', 'HOMEDRIVE') if k in os.environ]
        if available:
            state.directory = available[0]
    fn = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title='Excel file to open',
        parent=root,
        defaultextension='.xlsx',
        filetypes=(
            ('excel files', '*.xls*'), ('all files', '*.*')
        ),
    )
    if not fn:
        return
    state.directory = os.path.dirname(fn)
    state.worksheets_unlocked = 0
    state.workbook_unlocked = False
    state.path = fn
    widgets.fn['text'] = fn
    widgets.gobtn['state'] = 'enabled'
    widgets.status.delete(0, tk.END)


def on_backup():
    if widgets.backup.get() == 1:
        widgets.suffixlabel['state'] = 'enabled'
        widgets.suffixentry['state'] = 'enabled'
    else:
        widgets.suffixlabel['state'] = 'disabled'
        widgets.suffixentry['state'] = 'disabled'


def do_start():
    root.after(state.interval, step_open_zipfiles)


def do_exit(arg=None):
    """
    Callback to handle quitting.
    """
    root.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Detach from the command line on UNIX systems.
    if os.name == 'posix':
        if os.fork():
            sys.exit()    # Create the GUI window.
    root = tk.Tk(None)
    # Use a dialog window so that it floats even when using a tiling window
    # manager.
    root.attributes('-type', 'dialog')
    # Don't show hidden files in the file dialog
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53220711/how-to-avoid-hidden-files-in-file-picker-using-tkinter-filedialog-askopenfilenam
    try:
        # call a dummy dialog with an impossible option to initialize the file
        # dialog without really getting a dialog window; this will throw a
        # TclError, so we need a try...except :
        try:
            root.tk.call('tk_getOpenFile', '-foobarbaz')
        except tk.TclError:
            pass
        # now set the magic variables accordingly
        root.tk.call('set', '::tk::dialog::file::showHiddenBtn', '1')
        root.tk.call('set', '::tk::dialog::file::showHiddenVar', '0')
    except Exception:
        pass
    create_widgets(root, widgets)
    initialize_state(state)
    root.mainloop()
```

### Example of (3) unlocking excel files using a thread

```
"""Remove passwords from modern excel 2007+ files (xlsx, xlsm).
This is a multithreaded version of unlock-excel.pyw.  All the work that was
there done in steps in the mainloop is now done in a single additional thread.
There is some confusion whether tkinter is thread-safe.  That is, if one can
call tkinter functions and methods from any but the main thread.  The
documentation for Python 3 says “yes”.  Comments in the C source code for
tkinter say “its complicated” depending on how tcl is built.  *Many* online
sources say “no”, but that could just be an echo chamber effect.
The author has tested this code on FreeBSD 12.1-STABLE amd64 using CPython
3.7.7 combined with a tcl built with threading enabled.  There at least it
seems to work without problems.
"""

from types import SimpleNamespace
import os
import re
import shutil
import stat
import sys
import threading
import zipfile

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.font import nametofont
import tkinter as tk

__version__ = "2022.01.28"
widgets = SimpleNamespace()
state = SimpleNamespace()


def create_widgets(root, w):
    """Create the window and its widgets.
    Arguments:
        root: the root window.
        w: SimpleNamespace to store widgets.
    """
    # Set the font.
    default_font = nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
    default_font.configure(size=12)
    root.option_add("*Font", default_font)
    # General commands and bindings
    root.bind_all('q', do_exit)
    root.wm_title('Unlock excel files v' + __version__)
    root.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
    # First row
    ttk.Label(root, text='(1)').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
    w.fb = ttk.Button(root, text="Select file", command=do_file)
    w.fb.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="w")
    w.fn = ttk.Label(root)
    w.fn.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
    # Second row
    ttk.Label(root, text='(2)').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
    w.backup = tk.IntVar()
    w.backup.set(0)
    ttk.Checkbutton(root, text='backup', variable=w.backup,
                    command=on_backup).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')
    w.suffixlabel = ttk.Label(root, text='suffix:', state=tk.DISABLED)
    w.suffixlabel.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='ew')
    w.suffix = tk.StringVar()
    w.suffix.set('-orig')
    se = ttk.Entry(root, justify='left', textvariable=w.suffix, state=tk.DISABLED)
    se.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky='w')
    w.suffixentry = se
    # Third row
    ttk.Label(root, text='(3)').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew')
    w.gobtn = ttk.Button(root, text="Go!", command=do_start, state=tk.DISABLED)
    w.gobtn.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ew')
    # Fourth row
    ttk.Label(root, text='(4)').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='ew')
    ttk.Label(root, text='Progress:').grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')
    # Fifth row
    sb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical")
    w.status = tk.Listbox(root, width=60, yscrollcommand=sb.set)
    w.status.grid(row=4, rowspan=5, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew")
    sb.grid(row=4, rowspan=5, column=5, sticky="ns")
    sb.config(command=w.status.yview)
    # Ninth row
    ttk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=do_exit).grid(row=9, column=1, sticky='ew')


def initialize_state(s):
    """
    Initialize the global state.
    Arguments:
        s: SimpleNamespace to store application state.
    """
    s.directory = None


def statusmsg(text):
    """Append a message to the status listbox, and make sure it is visible."""
    widgets.status.insert(tk.END, text)
    widgets.status.see(tk.END)


def process_zipfile_thread():
    """Function to process a zip-file. This is to be run in a thread."""
    path = widgets.fn['text']
    statusmsg(f'Opening “{path}”...')
    first, last = path.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)
    if widgets.backup.get():
        backupname = first + widgets.suffix.get() + '.' + last
        remove = None
    else:
        backupname = first + '-orig' + '.' + last
        remove = backupname
    shutil.move(path, backupname)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(backupname, mode="r") as inzf, \
            zipfile.ZipFile(
                path, mode="w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=1
            ) as outzf:
        statusmsg(f'Reading “{path}”...')
        infos = [name for name in inzf.infolist()]
        statusmsg(f'“{path}” contains {len(infos)} internal files.')
        worksheets_unlocked = 0
        for idx, current in enumerate(infos, start=1):
            smsg = f'Processing “{current.filename}” ({idx}/{len(infos)})...'
            statusmsg(smsg)
            # Doing the actual work
            regex = None
            data = inzf.read(current)
            if b'sheetProtect' in data:
                regex = r'<sheetProtect.*?/>'
                statusmsg(f'Worksheet "{current.filename}" is protected.')
            elif b'workbookProtect' in data:
                regex = r'<workbookProtect.*?/>'
                statusmsg('The workbook is protected')
            else:
                outzf.writestr(current, data)
            if regex:
                text = data.decode('utf-8')
                newtext = re.sub(regex, '', text)
                if len(newtext) != len(text):
                    outzf.writestr(current, newtext)
                    worksheets_unlocked += 1
                    statusmsg(f'Removed password from "{current.filename}".')
    statusmsg('All internal files processed.')
    statusmsg(f'Writing “{path}”...')
    if remove:
        os.chmod(remove, stat.S_IWRITE)
        os.remove(remove)
    else:
        statusmsg('Removing temporary file')
    statusmsg(f'Unlocked {state.worksheets_unlocked} worksheets.')
    statusmsg('Finished!')
    widgets.gobtn['state'] = 'disabled'
    widgets.fn['text'] = ''


# Widget callbacks
def do_file():
    """Callback to open a file"""
    if not state.directory:
        state.directory = ''
        available = [os.environ[k] for k in ('HOME', 'HOMEDRIVE') if k in os.environ]
        if available:
            state.directory = available[0]
    fn = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title='Excel file to open',
        parent=root,
        defaultextension='.xlsx',
        filetypes=(('excel files', '*.xls*'), ('all files', '*.*')),
    )
    if not fn:
        return
    state.directory = os.path.dirname(fn)
    state.worksheets_unlocked = 0
    state.workbook_unlocked = False
    widgets.fn['text'] = fn
    widgets.gobtn['state'] = 'enabled'
    widgets.status.delete(0, tk.END)


def on_backup():
    if widgets.backup.get() == 1:
        widgets.suffixlabel['state'] = 'enabled'
        widgets.suffixentry['state'] = 'enabled'
    else:
        widgets.suffixlabel['state'] = 'disabled'
        widgets.suffixentry['state'] = 'disabled'


def do_start():
    worker = threading.Thread(target=process_zipfile_thread)
    worker.start()


def do_exit(arg=None):
    """
    Callback to handle quitting.
    """
    root.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Detach from the command line on UNIX systems.
    if os.name == 'posix':
        if os.fork():
            sys.exit()
    # Create the GUI window.
    root = tk.Tk(None)
    # Use a dialog window so that it floats even when using a tiling window manager.
    if os.name == 'posix':
        root.attributes('-type', 'dialog')
    # Don't show hidden files in the file dialog
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53220711/how-to-avoid-hidden-files-in-file-picker-using-tkinter-filedialog-askopenfilenam
    try:
        # call a dummy dialog with an impossible option to initialize the file
        # dialog without really getting a dialog window; this will throw a
        # TclError, so we need a try...except :
        try:
            root.tk.call('tk_getOpenFile', '-foobarbaz')
        except tk.TclError:
            pass
        # now set the magic variables accordingly
        root.tk.call('set', '::tk::dialog::file::showHiddenBtn', '1')
        root.tk.call('set', '::tk::dialog::file::showHiddenVar', '0')
    except Exception:
        pass
    create_widgets(root, widgets)
    initialize_state(state)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank alot for your answer! I would like to implement option 1) but im having some problems implementing it in my code. Im gonna edit my question to show you where im struggling.

Answer (score -1):

You have named the button with the same name as the function (go). Instead, you have to name it something else and pack it as well as the progress bar:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class TopLevelWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kargs):
        super().__init__(root, *args, **kargs)
        self.root = root
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Exportar excel", command=self.go)
        self.button.pack()  # packing button
        self.prog_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", mode="determinate")
        self.prog_bar.pack()  # packing progress bar

    def go(self):
        global dic_Data
        # Create word file
        value_bar = 100 / len(dic_Data)
        for k, v in dic_Data.items():
            time.sleep(1)  # to visualize the progressbar
            # Calculate some stuff
            # Create Pil images and add them to the word file
            # Create Matplotlib images and add them to the word file
            self.prog_bar["value"] += value_bar
            self.root.update_idletasks()
        # Save the word file
        self.quit()
        self.destroy()


class App:
    def __init__(self, root, *params):
        self.root = root
        # Code
        # dic_Data gets populated

    def open_window(self):
        popup = TopLevelWindow(self.root)
        popup.mainloop()


# some data to avoid divide by zero
dic_Data = {'a': 'Something', 'B': 'Something else', 'C': 'Nothing', 'D': 'Nothing else'}

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.open_window()  # calling the open window function
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: yes true my bad, was a mistake for this example, this is not the problem. Edited the question.

Comment: It works for me with some modifications (I've commented with the code)

Comment: For me the ```time.sleep``` hasnt work. I was wondering if maybe i need to make the inside of the for loop a function and then keep calling it somehow using the root.after function or something like that?? Dont really know tbh...

Comment: To make time.sleep work, you have to import time first (I've imported it automatically without thinking that I need to comment it for you, sorry)

Comment: Yes that part I know xd, I meant that even with time.sleep it still freezes my window